# What is this c++ syntax called

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I've been studying c++ and completed alot of syntax tasks, but as i try and moved into unreal engine, i stumbled on a syntax that seems to be unfamiliar with me.

```
UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) ) /*what is this?? I could pretty 
much understand anything written below except for this single line */

class ESCAPE_ROOM_API UPositionReporter : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UPositionReporter();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* 
    ThisTickFunction) override;

    
};
```

Comment: Seems that there are preprocessor macros in play, we cannot know without having more context of that code.

Comment: What are you including that provides that macro? Some codebases have very, ah, you might call them *creative* macro definitions. That code likely expands into something else that eventually gets compiled.

Comment: `UCLASS` is a define/MACRO. You have to show us what it is. (Look for `#define UCLASS` in the code).

Comment: Isn't `UCLASS` just a part of Unreal engine? Can't find link to docs, but various sources around the web say it's used to register something in the engine.

Comment: have you just tried googling UCLASS, it shows up as part of the meta information system Unreal Engine seems to use for reflection.

Answer (score 1):

`UCLASS` is a custom preprocessor macro defined by the Unreal Engine. You can use it to make the engine aware of your custom classes and add certain pieces of metadata known as specifiers to them. A list of the possible specifiers is available [on this page of the documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/GameplayArchitecture/Classes/Specifiers/index.html).